# erro de sintaxe no python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando resolver esse código mas na hora de rodar da erro de sintaxe na primeira linha.

```
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> segundos_str = input("por favor, entre com o número de segundos que deseja converter: ")
tota_segs = int(segundos_str)

horas = total_segs // 3600
segs_restantes = total_segs % 3600
minutos = segs_restantes // 60
segs_restantes_final = segs_restantes % 60

print(horas, "horas, ", minutos, "minutos e", segs_restantes_final, "segundos.")
```

[image: erro de sintaxe pytoh]

Comment: Tente colar os comandos no interpretador um de cada vez. Não parece haver erro de sintaxe na primeira linha. Deve estar havendo algum problema com um caracter não imprimível ao final da linha. Observando a sua tela, vê-se que o prompt da segunda linha não apareceu...

Comment: O que parece é que você copiou o código de algum lugar e colou dentro do Python Shell. Se for, todos esses dados inicias são desnecessários no arquivo e quebram a sintaxe.

Comment: Muito Obrigado a todos que colaboraram, estou muito agradecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro não é na primeira linha, mas na segunda. Sua variável `total_segs` está escrita de forma errada na segunda linha. Está `tota_segs`.

Esse erro vai ser evidenciado a partir da terceira linha de código, quando você faz um cálculo usando `total_segs` sem tê-la definido antes por causa do erro de digitação.

Tente sempre executar uma linha de cada vez no Shell. Isso ajuda a achar o erro.

Answer (score 3):

Você não escreveu um programa de Python.

Você copiou tudo o que estava na tela do interpretador interativo, e está tentando rodar isso como se fosse um programa.

Apesar das janelas serem parecidas, são ambientes com propósito **completamente** diferentes.

A primeira instrução de Python de fato que está aí, que poderia ser a primeira linha do seu programa é:

segundos_str = input("por favor, ... converter: ")

note que os caractéres `>>>` também não fazem parte do que você digita num programa - eles são o indicador de "digite a sua expressão de Python aqui", mas no ambiente interativo.

A sugestão, como está nos comentários, é você estudar Python no ambiente interativo, até ter alguma ideia do que está fazendo. Você copiou e colou o aviso da versão do Python como se fosse um programa, e não está entendendo que isso não faz parte da linguagem - tem que entender pelo menos isso antes de tentar fazer um programa - a sugestão é que você procure alguns tutoriais em nível bem iniciante mesmo - e pratique no modo interativo.

Comment: Olha a foto que ele postou. Ele está no ambiente interativo. E só tem todo o código do Python Shell na pergunta dele porque provavelmente deu Ctrl+C e Ctrl+V para mostrar pra gente. O erro está na variável `total_segs` que ele escreveu `tota_seg` por engano na segunda linha de código.

Comment: entre no idle.
Copie e cole o que ver no ambiente interativo para uma janela de arquivo.  Vá na opção "Run->Check Module". Você tem uma imagem exatamente igual a da imagem, com janela de erro, e highlght no "7" do Python 3.7

Comment: Jsbueno foi exatamente como você descreveu eu copiei e colei pra vocês verem o que estava acontecendo, mas agradeço muito a ajuda.

Comment: se esse era o problma, marque esta resposta como aceita (o checkzinho verde)